# On ru.SO, "Meta" wants (?) to be translated to russian in the (help) drop down

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

The drop down which replaces our usual "help" one doesn't have its last item title translated:

> [image]

Comment: You screenshots here have been very helpful, none of these really require translation prior to migrating. Thanks for taking so much time. :)